# Exchange Online Stream Subscription

Tags: c#, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to implement am application that listens to events in mailboxes from Exchange. Using group subscriptions to listen to mailboxes. 
We can create a connection with a lifetime of 30 min.  In my case I need to keep this connection alive for 24hrs. ie need to set the application to listen to events in the mailbox any time. The problem is that resubscribing connection sometimes throws an error

```
"The request failed. Unable to connect to the remote server".
```

But the next iteration will work fine.

Currently, I'm re-subscribing connection in every 30 min because in between that 30 there is a chance of appearing new mailboxes and I need to subscribe connection for that mailboxes too.

Also does this group stream subscription methods are stable when we use it for a large number of mailboxes?

Hope someone can help!

Comment: I've had similar problems with connecting to O365 resources. Works fine one attempt, next attempt gives you a DNS lookup failure or something similar... Very frustrating and I never found a way around it other than to keep trying until it decided to work, so if you do find a way that works I'd be interested!